# Querying a csv file with default values to columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas

[image]

I have to query this table with the query of type:

```
query(id,mtype,competition,gender,team1,team2,venue,date)
```

If every of the parameters in query is given, we can use if statements to store the results. But some of the parameters may not be provided. In that case, we have to consider all the column values.

Also, I have these data in a csv file. I want to read the csv file into a list and then query it. **The only catch is that if the user doesn't provide a parameter in the query, it should consider all the values in the column.**

Can someone suggest a way to do this with only few if-else statements or suggest some other way?

Comment: It would help if you could provide a couple of lines from the real csv file.

Comment: @PedroLobito It's the real csv file converted into a table. The rows and columns of the csv file has been converted to table.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Is your data on csv file or a database?

Comment: @PedroLobito It's in a csv file. The table here is only for representation of data.

Comment: Please show a sample of the **actual** csv file, just a couple of lines.

Comment: @PedroLobito Check the image in the question

Comment: to be able to test the code, I need the real csv....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas` with `read_csv` and `query` , i.e.:

```
import pandas as pd
# csv file should have the field names on the first row
# id,mtype,competition,gender,team1,team2,venue,date
df = pd.read_csv("the_file.csv", sep=",")
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) # convert date to a datetime object

mtype = "ODM"
sd = "2017-02-18"
ed = "2017-02-20"

df_query = df.query("mtype == '{}' and date > '{}' and date < '{}'".format(mtype, sd, ed))
print df_query
```

---

**Option 2**:

You can also convert the `csv` file into an `sqlite` db and issue the queries there, something like:

Import `csv` to `sqlite`:

```
import csv
import sqlite3
import os.path

csv_file = "csv_to_db.csv"
db_file = "csv_to_db.sqlite"
if not os.path.exists(db_file): # if no db_file we create one
    con = sqlite3.Connection(db_file,detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
    cur = con.cursor()
    # csv fields: id,mtype,competition,gender,team1,team2,venue,date
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE "venues" ("id" int primary key, "mtype" text,'
                ' "competition" text, "gender" text, "team1" text, '
                '"team2" text, "venue" text, "venue_date" date);')

    f = open(csv_file)
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

    cur.executemany('INSERT INTO venues VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', csv_reader)
    cur.close()
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    f.close()
```

Now we can start querying the db. You've asked:

> Can you provide an example of type `query(mtype,start_date,end_date)`
>   with all other parameter missing?

For that you can use:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file,detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
c = conn.cursor()

start_date = "2017-02-15"
end_date = "2017-02-20"

c.execute("SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE mtype='{query}' AND venue_date BETWEEN date('{start_date}') AND date('{end_date}')".format(table="venues", query="ODM", start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date))
all_rows = c.fetchall()
print( all_rows)
```

---

Grab the complete [gist](https://gist.github.com/x011/c7bda2bf36a8a1be3412889d3f23c1f5)

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), which provides a way to [filter rows](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html).

Comment: Can you provide an example of type query(mtype,start_date,end_date) with all other parameter missing?